# Parentheses Balance Code Miserably Runtime Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

Can someone help me debug the code? It is to check 'Parentheses Balance'. The input is a string with less than 10k characters.

Code:

```
def is_matched(expression):
    opening = tuple('({[')
    closing = tuple(')}]')
    # can use mapping = dict(zip(opening, closing))
    mapping = {'(': ')', '{': '}', '[': ']'}
    queue = []

    for letter in expression:
        if letter in opening:
            queue.append(mapping[letter])
        elif letter in closing:
            if not queue or letter != queue.pop():
                return False
    return not queue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input()
    if len(string) % 2 == 0: print (['No','Yes'][is_matched(string)])
    else: print ('No')
```

[Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKMoC.jpg)

There is 10 test cases, and my code passed all test cases except Test Case 3 where it miserably gave a **Runtime Error**. I have made it generate random input and 'self-run' for an hour, but haven't got any runtime error code. Can some expert point out the possible problem?

Thanks a LOT!

Comment: Do you have any information about the error?

Comment: So what is Test Case 3, and how is it different from Test Case 1, 2, 4 (etc.)? Please make your question self-containing. The image of the question text does not help much.

Comment: @khelwood Sadly No, it only says 'runtime error'.

Comment: @usr2564301 The image of the question text is the problem statement, and the Test Cases are not public, but I believe that Test Case 3 should not be a '10k length string' but instead shorter ones to see if your algorithm is actually right.

Comment: @usr2564301 Basically it doesn't tell you anything .-.